# navbar will not align left

Tags: html, css

Pretty self explanatory. I've spent hours messing around with the code...and cannot get the multicoloured navbar to align to the left to match rest of the content.

As you can see...there's a small gap on the left of about 20px.  I have no idea what's causing it.

I would like the green menu button and top navbar to move slightly to the left where the grey header starts.

I've tried adding the following to menu styles #session:

```
margin-left:0;
left:0;
padding-left:0;
```

doesn't work!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em0j490n/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ul has padding, that comes into play by default

Remove padding from #session

use

```
#session{
  padding:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to take the padding off

```
#session{ 
  /* other styles */
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#session{padding-left:0}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/em0j490n/8/)